# Are there any examples for statsmodels.gmm (Generalized Method of Moments)?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm trying to estimate some parameters using the GMM approach (**Generalized Method of Moments**, not Gaussian Mixture Model). I was hoping to use the package `statsmodels` if possible. The official description is listed [here](http://nipy.bic.berkeley.edu/nightly/statsmodels/doc/html/generated/statsmodels.sandbox.regression.gmm.GMM.html#statsmodels.sandbox.regression.gmm.GMM). However I got confused about where to specify the moment conditions. My model is not linear and does not use IV, so I cannot use `NonlinearIVGMM` and such. The "tutorials"/examples I found are only [for models with IVs](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/josef-pkt/6895915). I wonder if there are any examples to showcase how to use the more general `GMM`. Thanks.

Comment: I started to work on more examples here https://github.com/josef-pkt/misc/blob/master/notebooks/ex_gmm_gamma.ipynb

Comment: Also, I think you can always specify the instrument to be a vector of ones in NonlinearIVGMM.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You could see

[Issue with using statsmodels.sandbox.regression.gmm.GMM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49272902/issue-with-using-statsmodels-sandbox-regression-gmm-gmm)

and

https://github.com/josef-pkt/misc/blob/master/notebooks/ex_gmm_gamma.ipynb

to have a good picture of the function. Basically you have to declare a class using GMM function from statsmodels and then a subclass defining your moment conditions and then, run.